# Steve Jobs’s Stanford speech: this is the closest I've ever **gotten** to a college graduation?

Tags: word-choice, listening, got-gotten

I'm watching Steve Jobs’s speech at Stanford: http://news.stanford.edu/news/2005/june15/jobs-061505.html

There is a sentence I'm not clear, which of following is correct?

> and this is the closest I've ever **gotten** to a college graduation
>
> and this is the closest I've ever **got** to a college graduation

PS: Although the text on that page is the first one, but to my ears, it sounds like the second one. Which one is it to your ear?

Comment: What he says is clearly *gotten*, although he says it with an American accent, replacing the 't' with a glottal stop, and not emphasizing the 'n' very much.

Answer (score 2):

Either one is correct. The British tend to say 'got' where North Americans sometimes say 'gotten'.